# Flexible Container between min and max height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Let's say i have a container of fixed height and width, with text above a button (a colored container inside an inkWell). The text is long and on small devices might easily cause extra linebreaks, causing the button to be 'too high' and pushed out of bounds.

How can I give the Button a certain flexibility, to take space as available (but not too much) but as needed (so not to small).

```dart
Container(
   height: 160,
   width: 160,
   child: Column(
      children: [
         Text("Long Text aaa"),
         Inkwell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
               child(
                  Text("LogIn")
)))]))
```

Comment: Can you try using the `Flexible` widget?

Comment: `ConstrainedBox` might be what you want https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html

Comment: @GuillaumeRoux I tried that, but in that case it always takes the maxHeight, even if it is horribly overflowing

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana in what way should I use the Flexible here? I am still not quite sure how it works after using it tens of times i always just play around until i get it to work lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, the solution is to put the Inkwell in a ConstrainedBox in a Center in an Flexible

```dart
[...]
Text("Long Text aaa"),
Flexible(
   child: Center(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
         constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 60),
         child: InkWell(
[...]
```

That way it will work perfectly to fit the maximum space it can, while not becoming too big.